Cannot boot live USB after changing boot order via UEFI shell
I have an Acer travel mate running Arch Linux via EFISTUB. after last sy update I rebooted and got "No bootable device found" screen. To fix that I prepared a live arch USB and changed boot order to Hard drive it didn't fix the issue but now I can't even use the live USB. The system gets stuck at this output
[ 0.040284] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please updat e microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)

[ 0.1069381] DNAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x0000000000000000x000000009fffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes

If I boot without any USB I get
[ 0.040284] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please updat e microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)

[ 0.1069381] DNAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x0000000000000000x000000009fffffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes

[ 0.827742] /dev/root: Can't open blockdev 


what is the business related question or issue in here?

@djdomi I cannot boot my computer via HDD or USB

and what is the business relationship in here? if you have issues with your enduser equipment, please ask on superuser.com instead. on-topic;[help/on-topic], and what not to ask: [help/dont-ask] Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super Use
